# How can I convert this C# Linq query syntax to Linq method lambda syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<int>>> fuBenNPCDictionary;
。。。something;
IEnumerable<(string fuben, int pos)> query = from string fuben in fuBenNPCDictionary.Keys
                                                         let fubendict = fuBenNPCDictionary[fuben]
                                                         from int pos in fubendict.Keys
                                                         where fubendict[pos].Contains(npc.ID)
                                                         select (fuben, pos);
            if (query.Count() > 0)
                foreach ((string fuben, int pos) in query)
                {
                    placestr = "在" + jsonData.instance.SceneNameJsonData[fuben]["MapName"].str.ToCN() + "的第" + pos.ToString() + "位置";
                }
```

This query was originally a manual foreach, and then VS turned it into a Linq form. I'm not very good at linq and would like to convert it to  Linq method lambda syntax.

Comment: You do know that the query comprehension syntax is usually pretty close to identical in function to a well-crafted function-based LINQ statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
IEnumerable<(string key, int pos)> query = fuBenNPCDictionary.Keys
    .SelectMany(fuben => fuBenNPCDictionary[fuben]
        .Where(fubenDict => fubenDict.Value.Contains(npc.ID))
        .Select(fubenDict => (fuben, fubenDict.Key)));
```

#### Brief explanation

If you're unfamiliar with `SelectMany`, it might be easier to think about what this code will do instead for now:

```cs
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<(string key, int Key)>> query2 = fuBenNPCDictionary.Keys
    .Select(fuben => fuBenNPCDictionary[fuben]
        .Where(fubenDict => fubenDict.Value.Contains(npc.ID))
        .Select(fubenDict => (fuben, fubenDict.Key)));
```

So first we start with a `Select` on the `fuBenNPCDictionary.Keys`, taking each string key, and mapping it to the return of the subsequent code. In other words, for each key in the dict, do some sort of calculation or procedure, and give me a new list with the return from that procedure.

Inside this `Select` we can think about just what we're doing with one of the keys. We'll take the corresponding value to the key: `fuBenNPCDictionary[fuben]`, which is now the `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`. We want to filter the values in here to only include relevant `List<int>`s so we'll use the `Where`. Next we want to take those filtered `List`s and `Select` the tuple `(fuben, fubenDict.Key)`. Note that we get `fubenDict` from the direct scope of our current `Select`, but we can grab `fuben` from within the scope of our parent `Select`. It's a little easier to see that this is valid if we had written the statement like below (omitting the `Where` for brevity):

```cs
fuBenNPCDictionary.Keys.Select(fuben => 
{
    return fuBenNPCDictionary[fuben]
        // Note this is still inside the curly braces in which `fuben` is still in scope.
        .Select(fubenDict => (fuben, fubenDict.Key));
});
```

Putting this all together, the last thing left is that our `query2` contains an extra level of nesting that we didn't want: it's of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<(string key, int Key)>>` instead of `IEnumerable<(string key, int pos)>`. So instead of a single list we have a list of lists. The answer to this is to change the outer `Select` to `SelectMany` instead. A simple example for `SelectMany` would be that if you had an array that looked like

```
[ [1, 2], [1] ]
```

You could do a `SelectMany(x => x)` to get `[1, 2, 1]`, flattening the jagged array to a single array.

Comment: Thank you big guy, you are really awesome, thanks for your detailed answers, I learned a lot.